# Java Hibernate Criteria Average: BigDecimal instead of Double

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate criteria is mapping **Projections.avg("column")** to **Double**.

How can I force Hibernate to map that function to **BigDecimal**?

Hibernate is **hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be possible to subclass `AvgProjection` override `getTypes` to return BigDecimal and use this projection instead.

i.e.

```
public class AvgBDProjection extends AvgProjection{

    public AvgBDProjection(String propertyName) {
        super(propertyName);
    }

    public Type[] getTypes(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    throws HibernateException {
        return new Type[] { org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType.INSTANCE };
   }
}
```

Comment: Works! Though in **hibernate 4.1.9** it is **org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType.INSTANCE**.